# Calculating the number of times every letter of the alphabet appears in a series of strings in an ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, char

I have an ArrayList that stores strings, or notes, in the form of "walk the dog". I have a notes class with a method that prints the number of times each letter appears in the entire ArrayList. I'm supposed to declare and use a primitive array of ints of size 26 and turn each letter in the notebook into a char using the charAt method in the String class. Then I have to use that char to index into the appropriate location in the low-level array. This is my method so far but it's not finished:

```
public void printLetterDistribution() {
        ArrayList<Integer> aList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            String note = notes.get(i);
            for (int j = 0; j < note.length(); j++) {
                char letter = note.charAt(j);
                int code = (int)letter;
                aList.add(code);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(aList);

    }
```

I've hit a wall and I don't know how to continue. As you can see, I've tried to convert the letters to their character code but it's probably not the best way to do it and I'm still getting stuck. Can anybody help?

EDIT - Here is the entire notes class:

```
public class Notebook {
    private ArrayList<String> notes;

    public Notebook() { notes = new ArrayList<String>(); }

    public void addNoteToEnd(String inputnote) {
        notes.add(inputnote);
    }

    public void addNoteToFront(String inputnote) {
        notes.add(0, inputnote);
    }

    public void printAllNotes() {
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            System.out.print("#" + (i + 1) + " ");
            System.out.println(notes.get(i));
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public void replaceNote(int inputindex, String inputstring) {
        int index = inputindex - 1;
        if (index > notes.size() || index < 0) {
            System.out.println("ERROR: Note number not found!");
        } else {
            notes.set(index, inputstring);
        }
    }

    public int countNotesLongerThan(int length) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            String temp = notes.get(i);
            if (temp.length() > length) {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }

    public double averageNoteLength() {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            String temp = notes.get(i);
            int length = temp.length();
            sum += length;
        }
        double average = (double)(sum / notes.size());
        return average;
    }

    public String firstAlphabetically() {
        String min = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < notes.size(); j++) {
                if ((notes.get(i)).compareTo(notes.get(j)) < 0) {
                    min = notes.get(i);
                } else {
                    min = notes.get(j);
                }
            }
        }
        return min;
    }

    public void removeNotesBetween(int startnote, int endnote) {
        int start = startnote - 1;
        int end = endnote - 1;
        for (int i = end - 1; i > start; i--) {
            notes.remove(i);
        }
    }

    public void printNotesContaining(String findString) {
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            if (notes.get(i).contains(findString)) {
                System.out.println("#" + i + " " + notes.get(i));
            }
        }
    }

    public int countNumberOf(String letter) {
        int count = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            String note = (notes.get(i));
            for (int j = 0; j < note.length(); j++) {
                if (note.charAt(j) == letter.charAt(0)) {
                    count++;
                }
            }

        }
        return count;
    }

    public void findAndReplaceFirst(String old, String newWord) {
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            String note = notes.get(i);
            if (note.contains(old)) {
                int loc = note.indexOf(old);
                int len = old.length();
                String temp = note.substring(0, loc ) + note.substring(loc + len, note.length());
                String newString = temp.substring(0, loc) + newWord + temp.substring(loc, temp.length());
                notes.set(i, newString);
            } else {
                String newString = note;
                notes.set(i, newString);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printLetterDistribution() {
        int[] p = new int[26];
        for (int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
            p[i] = 0;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
            String note = notes.get(i);
            note = note.toLowerCase();
            for (int j = 0; j < note.length(); j++) {
                char letter = note.charAt(j);
                p[letter - 'a']++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(p);
    }

}
```

Comment: On a side note, it is preferable to use an enhanced for loop to loop through an ArrayList. Its syntax would look like: `for(String note : notes) { // logic for element note goes here }`

Comment: @MickMnemonic It's not because it's asking for a different format for the method and it's asking to count every instance of every letter i.e. a appears 6 times, b 4 times and so on.

Comment: @ch1maera, is this homework? The last four questions you've asked within an hour are pretty much about the same problem. The site is not intended to be used as a code-writing service.

Comment: @MickMnemonic yes, it is homework but I'm not asking anyone to write anything for me but rather to point out where I went wrong. The last three questions had pretty simple fixes that were caused by stupid mistakes and at most required minor modifications.

Comment: Okay. It would be good to mention homework in the question so that people know not to post code-only answers.

Comment: @Mick Mnemonic Thank you for the heads up. I will do that for future questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an int array of 26 length and increment the count of the index letter-'a';

```
int[] p = new int[26];
for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) p[i] = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < notes.size(); i++) {
        String note = notes.get(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < note.length(); j++) {
            char letter = note.charAt(j);
             if(letter>= 'a' && letter <= 'z')
               p[letter-'a']++;

 }
```

PS: I am assuming that the notes are in lowercase only. If it is not the case, use note.toLowerCase() to make them lower.

Since in your notes you can have spaces, I have updated the code.

Comment: You would have to include `note.toLowerCase()` first

Comment: I tried it but I'm getting an out of bounds exception on the second for loop.

Comment: Are all the characters only smaller case alphabets?

Comment: Can you show the content of the ArrayList notes?

Comment: @PriyanshGoel I just edited my original post to include it.

Comment: I meant the input... basically what is the content of ArrayList<String> notes? In other words, if you print the ArrayList<String> notes in the first line of this function, what is its output?

Comment: @PriyanshGoel [Go to the gym, Do homework, Finish project, Cook dinner, Take a shower, Study for test, Water plants, Clean room] This is what the notes list contains.

Comment: Updated the code and the answer.

Comment: Please let me know if it worked for you.

Comment: @PriyanshGoel yes it did. Thanks!